# Shared storage for web cluster

Tags: filesystems, cluster

Have a big question about shared/clustered/distributed file system for storage. It will shared storage for shared web hosting (web files + maildir) and OpenVZ containers storage . Have any one working example of such system?

The options are:

1. Lustre
2. GFS1/GFS2 - GFS2 - as I understand is EXPERIMENTAL...
3. NFS

This 3 systems which I consider for shared storage. Now I have storage with HW RAID 10 - 1TB.

NFS - As I know there will be problem with locking? 
GFS/Lustre - problems when there will be a lot of small files , what is typical for hosting environment and problems with maildir.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [ocfs2](http://oss.oracle.com/projects/ocfs2/). I have used it for a shared storage env for xen and it worked great.

NFS will not work due to locking issue like you explained and when I used gfs/gfs2 on shared nodes for a web cluster, gfs would always error out.

Comment: Ok... have decided to try GlusterFS ... any advise how to make replication? I know it is possible with GlusterFS itself, but the problem is .. that I have only one "good" server with hw raid10 and enough hdd throughput... And I want some thing like async mirroring to second server.. just in case to have actual data. But to do all reads from hw raid10...

Answer (score 0):

4:  [Gluster](http://www.gluster.com/)

5:  [ceph](http://ceph.newdream.net/)

Personally, until recently I'd go with OCFS2; but Oracle has abandoned development, so it might stagnate., as Canonical is the only left betting on it AFAIK.

Ceph seems technically the best solution; but it's still too experimental.

Gluster is mature, solid, fast and very complete.  Definitely a great solution.  The only shortcoming seems to be a little complex to administrate if you deviate from the well-known use cases. If you stay within a 'normal' config, it looks perfect.